# Issues with VLANs on Linux. Can ping hosts in other VLAN

Tags: linux, vlan

When I configure an ip address on a vlan interface from another vlan subnet, I can reach that other vlan subnet. But it should not be reachable.

For example:

- On the switch, the port is configured as tagged with vlan id 500 only
- On the Linux box the interface eth0.500 with ip address 192.168.10.30/24 can ping hosts in subnet 192.168.10.0/24, but those hosts are in vlan 3000

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Can you help me troubleshoot this, please?

There is an error on the Linux box:

```
kernel: received packet on eth0.3000 with own address as source address (addr: f4:03:43:ba:ca:c1 vlan:0)
```

STP is disabled on both the switch and the Linux box.

What I've tried:

- rp_filter=1 - no effect
- arp_ignore=1 or 2 - no effect
- arp_filter=1 - no effect

It doesn't matter if it's a normal interface or bond or bridge, the behavior is the same.

There is no errors on the Switch.

No default route is set both on the switch and the Linux box.

In Wireshark when capturing traffic on eth0 there is a vlan tag = 500 on the packets.

Thank you!

EDIT 1:
Routing table on Linux box:

```
192.168.10.0/24 dev eth0.500 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.10.30
```

EDIT 2: Diagram
[diag1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RA0u.png)

EDIT 3: tracepath and ping

```
tracepath 192.168.10.31
1?: [LOCALHOST]  pmtu 1500
1:  ??? 0.714ms !H
1:  ??? 0.516ms !H
    Resume: pmtu 1500

ping -c 2 192.168.10.31
PING 192.168.10.31 (192.168.10.31) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.10.31: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.230 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.10.31: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.197 ms

--- 192.168.10.31 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1059ms

rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.197/0.213/0.230/0.016 ms
```

EDIT 4: ip addresses

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f4:03:43:ba:ca:c1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eth0.500@eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f4:03:43:ba:ca:c1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.10.30/24 scope global eth0.500@eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: eth0.3000@eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f4:03:43:ba:ca:c1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: Are the packages routed somewhere else?

Comment: Can you add the routing table?

Comment: Default route not set on Linux box, and no additional routes as well. The Switch is Mellanox SN2010M, on this switch routing is enabled, but only management interface in use, even no ip addresses on VLAN interfaces. Can it be Cisco ASA with same-security-traffic permit intra-interface enabled?

Comment: @eKKiM added at the end of post

Comment: Do the other hosts in 192.168.10.0/24 in vlan 3000 show up in your ARP table?
Maybe a small diagram with the hosts, switch and Cisco ASA could be helpfull too!

Comment: `eth0.500 with ip address 192.168.10.30/24 can ping hosts in subnet 192.168.10.0/24` - 10.0/24 ***is*** the ***same*** subnet as 10.0/24. What does `tracepath` show?

Comment: @eKKiM diagram at the end of post, in arp table i can see other hosts if i ping or ssh into them.

Comment: @vidarlo the problem is that i can reach other hosts in different vlan with same subnet, so i can configure ip address from subnet in vlan 3000 on interface with vlan 500 and reach subnet in vlan 3000. tracepath at the end.

Comment: Do you have anything configured on eth0.3000? Eventually add the output of ip addr? I also have a feeling there could be other routes on the routing table for the other NICs?

Comment: @eKKiM ip addrs in last edit. Routing table in the edit 1, there is no other routes.

Comment: Can you ping the host using the following command?: ping -c 2 192.168.10.31 -I eth0.500

Also if you remove vlan 3000 from the host can you still reach the other machines?

Also lets move to chat to avoid spamming the comments: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131659/issues-with-vlans-on-linux-can-ping-hosts-in-other-vlan

Comment: @eKKiM i can reach other hosts with or without eth0.3000 interface on the host with your command. Can't answer you in the chat because of low reputation, sorry.

Comment: @eKKiM Is the MAC address in the ARP table the remote machine MAC or some router/switch MAC? Yes, MAC address of the host is present in arp table on remote machine

Comment: @eKKiM Do you bridge the VLAN's on the switch? What do you mean? VLAN mapping or Q-in-Q? No, i'm not using any of this.